# Does $\Bbb E[X|Z]=\Bbb E[Y|Z]$ if $X,Y$ are identically distributed random variable?

Tags: probability

Does $\Bbb E[X|Z]=\Bbb E[Y|Z]$ if $X,Y$ are identically distributed random variable, where $Z$ is a third random variable? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. **Example:** $Z=X$. In this case $\Bbb E[X|Z] = Z$ but $\Bbb E[Y|Z]=E[Y]$.

Comment: Why is the last equality true?